# Building Qt fro Source with MSYS2 / MinGW 64 - ICU headers not found

Tags: qt, icu, msys, mingw-w64

I followed the instructions from [MinGW-64-bit](https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit), using Option A: build Qt in MSYS2-shell & MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell.

I downloaded the source code

```
git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
perl init-repository
git checkout 5.8
```

After installing all prerequisites I build OpenSSL and ICU - installed in

- /usr/local/openssl
- /usr/local/icu

But from there on the instructions are not so clear. It's stated to use a windows command shell to set some environment variables. But later I'm using the MSYS2 64 Bit shell, so these have no effect. Here is what I did:

```
export INCLUDE=/usr/local/icu/include:/usr/local/openssl/include
export LIB=/usr/local/icu/lib:/usr/local/openssl/lib
export QMAKESPEC=
export QTDIR=
windows2unix() { local pathPcs=() split pathTmp IFS=\;; read -ra split <<< "$*"; for pathTmp in "${split[@],}"; do pathPcs+=( "/${pathTmp//+([:\\])//}" ); done; echo "${pathPcs[*]}"; }; systemrootP=$(windows2unix "$SYSTEMROOT"); export PATH="$PWD/qtbase/bin:$PWD/gnuwin32/bin:/c/msys64/mingw64/bin:/c/msys64/usr/bin:/c/msys64/usr/local/icu/lib"
export MAKE_COMMAND=

mkdir qt-build
cd qt-build

../qt5/configure -prefix /opt/qt -debug-and-release -opensource -confirm-license -platform win32-g++ -developer-build -icu -I /usr/local/icu/include -opengl desktop -openssl -plugin-sql-odbc -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

The configure script stops with the following error:

```
ERROR: Feature 'icu' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.icu' failed.
```

In Qt's config.log I found:

```
looking for library icu
Trying source 0 (type inline) of library icu ...
 => source failed condition 'config.win32 && !features.shared'.
Trying source 1 (type inline) of library icu ...
+ cd C:\msys64\home\asp\qt-build\qtbase\config.tests\unix\icu && C:\msys64\home\asp\qt-build\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared console" "LIBS += -licuin -licuuc -licudt" C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu
+ cd C:\msys64\home\asp\qt-build\qtbase\config.tests\unix\icu && set MAKEFLAGS=& C:/msys64/usr/bin/make
> g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -IC:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu -I. -IC:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o icu.o C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu/icu.cpp
> C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu/icu.cpp:40:28: fatal error: unicode/utypes.h: No such file or directory
>  #include <unicode/utypes.h>
>                             ^
> compilation terminated.
> make: *** [Makefile:155: icu.o] Fehler 1
 => source failed verification.
Trying source 2 (type inline) of library icu ...
 => source failed condition '!config.win32'.
test config.corelib.libraries.icu FAILED
```

Why doesn't the script find the includes? I set them as

- parameter '-I /usr/local/icu/include'
- export INCLUDE=/usr/local/icu/include:/usr/local/openssl/include

I also tried

- parameter '-I /C/msys64/usr/local/icu/include'
- export INCLUDE=/C/msys64/usr/local/icu/include:/C/msys64/usr/local/openssl/include

Is there another possibility to give the correct INCLUDE path to the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved this problem!

I removed the complete qt5 folder and started from the beginning. Then I got the following error:

```
looking for library icu
Trying source 0 (type inline) of library icu ...
  => source failed condition 'config.win32 && !features.shared'.
Trying source 1 (type inline) of library icu ...
+ cd C:\msys64\home\asp\qt-build\qtbase\config.tests\unix\icu && C:\msys64\home\asp\qt-build\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared console" "INCLUDEPATH += C:/msys64/usr/local/icu/include" "LIBS += -licuin -licuuc -licudt" C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu
+ cd C:\msys64\home\asp\qt-build\qtbase\config.tests\unix\icu && set MAKEFLAGS=& C:/msys64/usr/bin/make clean && set MAKEFLAGS=& C:/msys64/usr/bin/make
> rm -f icu.o
> g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -IC:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu -I. -IC:/msys64/usr/local/icu/include -IC:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o icu.o C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/unix/icu/icu.cpp
> g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o icu.exe icu.o  -licuin -licuuc -licudt 
> C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -licuin
> C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -licuuc
> C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -licudt
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [Makefile:62: icu.exe] Fehler 1
 => source failed verification.
Trying source 2 (type inline) of library icu ...
  => source failed condition '!config.win32'.
test config.corelib.libraries.icu FAILED
```

So the headers could be found this time! But now the ICU lib couldn't be linked. So I added '-L /C/msys64/usr/local/icu/lib' and tried again:

```
../qt5/configure -prefix /opt/qt -debug-and-release -opensource -confirm-license -platform win32-g++ -developer-build -icu -I /C/msys64/usr/local/icu/include -L /C/msys64/usr/local/icu/lib -opengl desktop -openssl -plugin-sql-odbc -nomake examples -nomake tests

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into 'C:\msys64\opt\qt'
```

Comment: Minor point, but `C:/msys64/usr/local` is a bad choice for mingw-w64 software, you'd be better using `C:/msys64/mingw64/local` or `C:/msys64/mingw32/local`.